# translate the_title() with .po & .mo

Tags: functions, translation

i need to translate the_title().

I am using code:

```
<?php _e(the_title()); ?>
```

but not working ... any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Since, 'the_title()' is not a static word, you can't directly translate it. Its value can be dynamic and saved in the database. So, you can either use plugins like 'WPML', 'qTranslate' or just learn how to do translation for the values which are saved in database.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer. Where to find about: " learn how to do translation for the values which are saved in database."

Comment: I have done translation for hardcoded words in the code, so far. But have never done translation for dynamic words like 'the_title()'. See, if you can spent some tome to figure out how such plugins do this (as far as I know, they save the translation in the database). You can do some research over any free plugin like qTranslate https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/